# Build issue angular 5 has no exported member 'DSVRowAny'

Tags: d3.js

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/d3-fetch/index.d.ts(9,10): error TS2305: Module '"F:/AprotechSolutions/ems-beam-webapp/node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index"' has no exported member
'DSVParsedArray'.
node_modules/@types/d3-fetch/index.d.ts(9,26): error TS2305: Module '"node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index"' has no exported member 'DSVRowString'.
node_modules/@types/d3-fetch/index.d.ts(9,40): error TS2305: Module '"/node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index"' has no exported member 'DSVRowAny'.
node_modules/@types/d3-fetch/index.d.ts(9,57): error TS2497: Module '"/node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index"' resolves to a non-module entity
and cannot be imported using this construct.
node_modules/@types/d3/index.d.ts(24,15): error TS2498: Module '"/node_modules/@types/d3-dsv/index"' uses 'export =' and cannot be used with 'export *'.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems, this issue due to update

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3-dsv/v/0.4.4?activeTab=versions

I have this problem too.

Try to fix lib version to 1.0.31 in your `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3-dsv": "1.0.31"
}
```

Comment: What if you are using "@types/d3": "^5.0.0" ?

Comment: This solved my problem. As I have "@types/d3": "^5.0.0", I just did `npm install @types/d3-dsv@1.0.31 --save-dev`

Comment: It wasn't necessary for me to lock to the previous version. I just needed to lock to a 1.x.x version. See my answer for additional context.

Comment: Okay Thanks We can try.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the issue *may* have been the "latest" tag for @types/d3-dsv switching from the 1.0.x versions (that contain exports for DSVRowString etc.) to 0.4.x (that don't), as described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26000). Hopefully there will be a response to the issue that will remove the need for the version pinning.

So, at least for me, it was enough to pin to the latest 1.x.x version, and not necessary to lock to previous version (as suggested in another answer), e.g:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/d3-dsv": "^1.0.32"
}
```

Update (28/05/18):

Looks like the issue is temporarily resolved due to the release of version 1.0.33 causing the "latest" tag to point back to the 1.0.x branch. However, as per [a comment on the GitHub issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26000#issuecomment-392462927) this isn't necessarily a permanent fix, and another release of the 0.4.x code could cause the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i will try.

Comment: This seems like it should be the accepted answer as it doesn't involve a downgrade @Komdosh

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be resolved, I just built my application without any problems any without the devDependencies for d3-dsv.

There is was an update to the package a couple of hours ago:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3-dsv/v/0.4.4?activeTab=versions

Comment: Until the next time it happens (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26000#issuecomment-392462927). See my answer for a resolution that doesn’t mean locking to an old release if it does!